# Linux Mint 19 - mirror iPhone

Tags: linux-mint, iphone, mirroring

I have been doing some googling to figure out a way to ***mirror my iPhone in Linux Mint 19***, using either USB or WiFi-direct (AirServer-ish).

I've been trying several work-arounds, e.g. Linux' Totem (Video player), using Wine to install QuickTime Player (and other mirror-apps for Windows).

I've also tried using Darling (a solution for installing Mac OS apps on Linux), but it seems like Darling doesn't work with Linux Mint 19.

I was wondering if anyone could give a, more or less, detailed tutorial on making it possible to mirror iPhone on Linux (Mint 19, that is). I have no trouble using a commercial solution (licensed mirroring apps).

Comment: I discovered a solution. Look at my own answer below for a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this, using Google Chrome browser.

On iPhone, there is an app in App Store which is called Mirror to Windows PC (it costs $4.99 though.

Follow this link for detailed instructions on how to mirror your iPhone to Google Chrome, using Linux:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mirror-to-windows-pc/id1350663974?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually, there is a way to force mirroring iPad onto Linux Mint via an  Android  smartphone. I had struggled for days trying to find out a simple solution which meant avoiding the use of the Terminal or whatsoever. And there it is: **using mirroring from the iPad to a smartphone which mirrors to your laptop.**

This is how it works for me on a Linux Mint 19 Acer Aspire 3:

1. Download ApowerMirror both onto your iPad and smartphone
2. Download ScreenMirror from Play Store onto your smartphone (Follow instructions. That is: after downloading the app, get to http://www.screenmirrorapp.com/)
3. Launch Screen mirror from the smartphone to your laptop
4. Sync ApowerMirror both on your iPad and your smartphone
5. Voilà. Simple, easy and wireless.

[image]